# Windows 7. Экспорт сертификата РДП сервера

Tags: windows, rdp, wireshark

Здравствуйте. В учебных целях пытаюсь разобраться в протоколе RDP. В частности в том его варианте где используется CredSSP. Проблема заключается в том, что никак не получается экспортировать сертификат сервиса удаленных рабочих столов в windows 7 что бы подсунуть его wireshark. Причина в том, что изначально он имеет неэкспортируемый ключ. Пытался импортировать другой сертификат созданный через openssl, Сертификат ставится, но все равно выдается в итогде изначальный при подключении по РДП. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает, как так вывернутся, что бы можно было добавить сертификат в wireshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решен данный вопрос был установкой на VirtualBox windows server 2008. В нем нет проблем с заменой сертификата. Весь RDP трафик проходящий по TLS, был успешно прочитан через Microsoft Message Analyzer